# Strange tex4ht behaviour with Devanagari text

Tags: xetex, tex4ht, polyglossia, tex4ebook, devanagari

I'm currently writing some text citing a lot of international literature, which I like to quote genuinely i.e., without using latin approximations. This in general works well using `polyglossia`, but somehow Devanagari appears to be different. The following test works as expected in `XeLaTeX`, but produces no Devanagari (Sanskrit) with `tex4ebook` - and no paragraphs and an error at `\begin{document}`. All the other foreign fonts work well.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek,hebrew,sanskrit,arabic,thai}

\newfontfamily\latinfont[Script=Latin,Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Sans Devanagari}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Ligatures=TeX,Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Noto Sans Arabic}
\newfontfamily{\thaifont}[Script=Thai]{Noto Sans Thai}

\begin{document}

This is some English test text.

The apology of Socrate: \textgreek{ἀπολογία Σωκράτους}

And some text in Sanskrit: \textsanskrit{न चाशुश्रूषवे वाच्यं न च मां योऽभ्यसूयति}

Some Arabic: \textarabic{لكن لا بد أن أوضح لك أن كل}

Some Hebrew:  \texthebrew{בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ}

Some Thai: \textthai{โปรแซลมอน เยลลี่ แพตเทิร์นสไตล์สเต็ป จังโก้ สหัสวรรษ}

\end{document}
```

So, with `XeLaTeX` all text is shown. With `tex4ebook` everything is there except for the Devanagari text. It is simply missing altogether in the `.html`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='originator' /> 
<!--  xhtml,charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4,html  --> 
<meta content='CorruptDevanagari.tex' name='src' /> 
<link type='text/css' href='CorruptDevanagari.css' rel='stylesheet' /> 
</head><body>
   This is some English test text.
   The apology of Socrate: ἀπολογία Σωκράτους
   And some text in Sanskrit:
   Some Arabic: لكن لا بد أن أوضح لك أن كل
   Some Hebrew: בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ
   Some Thai: โปรแซลมอน เยลลี่ แพตเทิร์นสไตล์สเต็ป จังโก้ สหัสวรรษ   

</body></html>
```

If I paste the text into the `.html` it is well displayed in the browser. Another puzzling observation is that `<p>` markup is missing.

Beyond that I get the following error when using the `-a debug` switch, which however appears unrelated to the Devanagari issue:

```
Package polyglossia Warning: Patchingbiditablefailed! on input line 25.

! You can't use `\relax' after \the.
\NoHtmlEnv ....0pt\ht:everypar {\the \ht:everypar 
                                              }
l.25 \begin{document}
                 
?
```

This error does not appear with `XeLaTeX` and I have no clue, what I could possibly do about it - or if I have to care in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XeTeX mode, TeX4ht defines Unicode characters as active, so that they can be inserted into the output as special markers, which will produce the same Unicode characters in the HTML output. Since there are tens of thousands of Unicode characters, we only declare those that are needed based on the font scripts. Because of the bug in the `\newfontfamily` processing, this doesn't work correctly when you use the optional argument before the font name.

Here is the fixed version. Save the following code as `usepackage-fontspec.4ht`:

```
% usepackage-fontspec.4ht (2020-09-02-14:24), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2017-2020 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2020-09-02-14:24}

% \RequirePackage{expl3}% we need to disable them before loading
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \fontspec_ht_scripts
\gdef\texfourhtfontspecloaded{yes}% used to prevent subsequent loading of this file
\ExplSyntaxOff
\ifdefined\XeTeXversion%
\xenunidelblock{Latin-expl3}% expl3 package makes some characters active
\xeuniuseblock{Latin-expl3}% and define again
\fi%
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \tl_gset:Nx \l__fontspec_nfss_enc_tl {T1}
  \tl_gset:Nx \g_fontspec_encoding_tl {T1}
  \tl_gset:Nx \l__fontspec_ttfamily_encoding_tl {T1}
  \tl_gset:Nx \l__fontspec_sffamily_encoding_tl {T1}
  \tl_gset:Nx \l__fontspec_rmfamily_encoding_tl {T1}
  \seq_new:N \fontspec_ht_fontfamilies
  \ifdefined\XeTeXversion
  \keys_define:nn {fontspec4ht}{
    Script .code:n = \xeuniuseblock{#1}
  }
  \else
  \keys_define:nn {fontspec4ht}{
    Script .code:n = \seq_put_right:Nn \fontspec_ht_scripts {#1}
  }
  \fi
\cs_set:Nn \fontspec_set_family:Nnn
 {
  % \tl_set:Nn \l__fontspec_family_label_tl { #1 }
  % \__fontspec_select_font_family:nn {#2}{#3}
  % \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_fontspec_family_tl
  \def#1{\relax}
 }


\prg_set_conditional:Nnn \fontspec_if_fontspec_font: {TF,T,F}
{
  \prg_return_false:
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \setmainfont { O{} m O{} }
 {
   % Optional argument can be in both first and third parameter
  \keys_set_known:nn {fontspec4ht}{#1}
  \keys_set_known:nn {fontspec4ht}{#3}
  \seq_put_right:Nn \fontspec_ht_fontfamilies {#2}
  \use:x { \exp_not:n { \DeclareRobustCommand \rmfamily }
   {
    \relax
   }
  }
  \normalfont
  \ignorespaces
 }

 % define aliases for other user commands
\cs_set_eq:NN \fontspec\setmainfont
\cs_set_eq:NN \setsansfont\setmainfont
\cs_set_eq:NN \setmonofont\setmainfont
\cs_set_eq:NN \setromanfont\setmainfont
\cs_set_eq:NN \setmathrm\setmainfont
\cs_set_eq:NN \setmathsf\setmainfont
\cs_set_eq:NN \setboldmathrm\cs_set_eq:NN
\cs_set_eq:NN \setmatht\cs_set_eq:NN



\DeclareDocumentCommand \newfontfamily { m O{} m O{} }
 {
  % \fontspec_set_family:cnn { g__fontspec_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _family } {#2} {#3}
  \keys_set_known:nn {fontspec4ht}{#2}
  \keys_set_known:nn {fontspec4ht}{#4}
  \seq_put_right:Nn \fontspec_ht_fontfamilies {#3}
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:N \DeclareRobustCommand \exp_not:N #1
     {
       \relax
     }
   }
 }
 % \tl_set:Nn \g_fontspec_encoding_tl{T1}
 %  \tl_set_eq:NN \encodingdefault\g_fontspec_encoding_tl
 \DeclareDocumentCommand \addfontfeatures {m}
 {
   \keys_set_known:nn {fontspec4ht}{#1}
   \typeout{Add font features}
 }
 \cs_set_eq:NN \addfontfeature \addfontfeatures
  \global\expandafter\let\csname ver@fontenc.sty\endcsname\relax
  \global\expandafter\let\csname opt@fontenc.sty\endcsname\relax
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\edef\TivhTcats{%
  \catcode`:=12%
  \catcode`@=\the\catcode`@%
}

\endinput
```

With this change, you should get the correct result:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `-l` option instead of `-x`. This will use a different method for the Unicode handling, thanks to LuaTeX. It doesn't suffer from these problems with undefined Unicode characters.

Regarding the Polyglossia bug, I cannot reproduce that. Which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll dig into this tonight. I'm using TeX on Debian Bullseye i.e., texlive Version: 2020.20210202-3. And yes, upgrade to Bookworm with texlive 2022 is pending.

Comment: @LarsHanke ah, TeX Live 2020 is quite old. I've fixed some Polyglossia-related bugs since then. Even TeX Live 2022 will have some bugs that were fixed in the current distribution.

Comment: So it may be the better alternative to try installing polyglossia from CTAN into  /usr/local/ first?

Comment: @LarsHanke no, it will probably depend on updated LaTeX kernel and other things. It is better to use distro files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solves this issue and I guess I first upgrade to TeXLive 2022 before I start addressing any more issues.